# prepare called on a closed database rails rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, rspec-rails, spork

I am trying to integrate BDD in my rails app via rspec. I am using guard and spork-rails to speed the monitoring process up. I am getting this error:

```
An error occurred in an after hook 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: ArgumentError: prepare called on a closed database: 
rollback transaction occurred at /Users/davidhahn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in initialize
```

I ran `rake db:test:prepare` and it ran without any errors. Since I'm using sqlite I checked to make sure that the `user_man_test.sqlite` file was in `db/`. My test is just a simple integration test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do
  describe "Login Page" do                                                 
    it "should have the h1 'Welcome to User Management'" do                
      visit '/log_in'                                                      
      page.should have_selector('h1', text: 'Welcome to User Management')  
    end                                                                    
  end                                                                      

  describe "Login" do                                                      
    before { visit '/log_in' }                                             

    describe "with invalid information" do                                 
      before { click_button "Login" }                                      

      it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Welcome to User Management') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }
    end                                                                    
  end                                                                      
end
```

My spec_helper.rb looks like:

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'spork'
Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
    config.order = "random"
  end
end
Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
end
```

~
Thanks for the help

Comment: I changed to mysql which corrected the error which leads me to believe that it was something wrong in the configuration of my sqlite3.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of spending hours trying to configure spork properly, I would advise you to look at [Zeus](https://github.com/burke/zeus). I'm sorry if this doesn't exactly answer your question, but I spent almost one year with spork, had tons of trouble configuring every time that I added a new test gem, and when I made the switch, everything magically worked (and in my experience, Zeus' performance is much better than Spork).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've actually stopped using guard and spork altogether, but I will try out zeus.

Comment: @DavidHahn if this answers your question, you should accept it as an answer so others know your question is solved ;).